# Childbrowser plugin iOS error

Tags: javascript, cordova, backbone.js, requirejs

```
webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: 
delegate: <NSRangeException> *** -[JKArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) 
beyond bounds (1)
```

That is the error i'm receiving. I have this one.

```
e.preventDefault();
var cb = ChildBrowser.instal();
if(!cb){ plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage("http://google.com"); }
```

I'm using Backbone, require, and Cordova

Comment: How did you resolv this issue?